Spring JAR can not find log4j2-spring.xml config file
I am using Log4J for logging and I have a config file in src/main/resources/log4j2-spring.xml
Running from IDE it works correctly but when I generate the JAR, open the jar it gives me this exception:
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'src/main/resources/log4j2-spring.xml'
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\target\src\main\resources\log4j2-spring.xml (The system can not find the specified path)

I don't need to manually write or read this file, just want to make the JAR work so I don't need to do anything like getResourcesAsStream(). How to make JAR to find this config file? maybe there's some config for pom or something?

If you are using Spring Boot, have you set the log config location in the project properties? Something like that, perhaps?
logging.config=src/main/resources/log4j2-spring.xml

Looking to the error, Spring is trying to search for this file in target\src\main\resources, thus concatenating the basic target classpath with the given relative path.
You should use the classpath: variable:
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-spring.xml

Perhaps, running in the IDE, the path is managed correctly because of the base launch path.
Keep in mind that log4j2-spring.xml is one of the "standard" names that Spring Boot is looking for in context startup, so you don't need to specify in the property file.

solved by changing src/main/resources path to "classpath", thanks

src/main/resources/log4j2-spring.xml

C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\target\src\main\resources\log4j2-spring.xml

you can use
classpath:log4j2-spring.xml

See

Reference document https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/resources.html#resources-implementations-urlresource:~:text=prefix%20(such%20as-,classpath%3A,-)%2C%20it%20creates%20an
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access


solved by changing src/main/resources path to "classpath", thanks

When you can vote up, please vote up for me. Thank you :)
